# heat map in R to show correlation

Tags: r

I need help making a heatmap, please.

I want to make a heatmap of this dataset (the dataset is larger but this will show the structure):

```
 data.str <-
   structure(
     list(
       Metabolite = c(
         "Glucose_%",
         "Fructose_%",
         "Sugars_%",
         "Sugars.as.mono_%",
         "Starch_%",
         "Starch.as.mono_%",
         "Glutamic_%",
         "Proline_%",
         "Biotin_%",
         "C20.2cn6_%"
       ),
       Difference_S_HDL_CE_pct = c(
         27.0580967,
         29.4741588,
         30.6727965,
         37.044534,
         0.00592,
         0.00924,
         2.8089622,
         4.3284966,
         3.616572,
         16.6234106
       ),
       Difference_L_HDL_TG = c(
         20.3426932,
         19.6578323,
         6.1540709,
         6.618907,
         20.7397107,
         22.7363078,
         5.7014121,
         6.0341221,
         5.9002733,
         5.0788391
       ),
       Difference_Gln = c(
         20.2203384,
         21.9353406,
         17.1303398,
         17.3148438,
         8.7804598,
         7.0612042,
         0.5848933,
         0.3856946,
         0.0748362,
         10.761994
       ),
       Difference_S_LDL_FC_pct = c(
         20.1171041,
         21.1194979,
         19.0084278,
         22.7941105,
         0.6624931,
         1.2516315,
         0.4276689,
         1.3559095,
         1.7227713,
         18.2480865
       ),
       Difference_Pyruvate = c(
         17.5854511,
         19.9410449,
         12.7105925,
         11.9623687,
         10.4788242,
         8.6559229,
         0.0189435,
         0.0239544,
         0.00312,
         16.7369868
       ),
       Difference_L_LDL_TG = c(
         13.250508,
         13.9865028,
         13.4782952,
         14.1116228,
         4.0569956,
         3.3975936,
         0.8144706,
         0.7677175,
         0.0572463,
         14.4629904
       ),
       Difference_S_HDL_C_pct = c(
         12.9346568,
         13.1410302,
         16.6905244,
         22.6788084,
         1.7590544,
         1.3980602,
         2.9658478,
         4.8456946,
         2.7936213,
         27.68029
       ),
       Difference_S_HDL_PL_pct = c(
         12.864684,
         11.9193723,
         10.8118128,
         11.8431789,
         1.0692856,
         1.4855054,
         1.9670692,
         1.3530411,
         8.5227632,
         -1.6739852
       ),
       Difference_M_LDL_TG_pct = c(
         12.8530009,
         11.4667269,
         13.5677286,
         16.3305456,
         0.9506285,
         0.5322617,
         0.8908791,
         1.898937,
         2.9490729,
         29.5990618
       ),
       Difference_L_LDL_C_pct = c(
         12.5509812,
         13.624991,
         12.482877,
         13.1641219,
         0.3197067,
         0.0195839,
         8.7725257,
         7.2044468,
         0.0122509,
         8.4407425
       ),
       Difference_IDL_TG = c(
         12.0014,
         11.378059,
         6.0707129,
         6.2593626,
         8.3150096,
         9.6032892,
         4.2182798,
         3.8636934,
         4.2984429,
         1.8889026
       )
     ),
     row.names = c(NA, 10L),
     class = "data.frame"
   )
```

the maximum value I have is around 40, so I want the scale to be between -2 and 45. The color is red and the darker is the higher is the value.

this is a good example of what I'm looking for

[image]

the only difference is that I want it red, scale from -2 to 40 and I want to divide the variables on the y-axis into subgroups (for example if I want to show that the lower three variables on the y-axis in this blue heatmap "col 1, col 10 and col 2" belong to a specific group like lipids, and each other 3 variables are from same subgroup like ratios, ketone bodies, etc.)

differences in metabolite should be on the y-axis and nutrients should be on x-axis. Also, I need values that are more than 5 to be printed on the corresponding square.

thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does most of what you have asked for, apart from grouping the y axis variables. You have not supplied any specific information about how you would like these to be shown (with facets, with dividing lines, with different colored labels, or some other way), and there is no way to know how you want these groupings to be defined (the ones in your example data seem to be all lipid related, apart from `Gln` and I don't know what that means despite having some domain-specific knowledge here).

```r
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(data.str, -1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Metabolite, name, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(value > 5, round(value), '')),
            color = 'white') +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'red', high = '#560000') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]